# Is there a way to apply a gradle task to a dependency?

Tags: java, gradle, compilation, instrumentation

I have written a fairly simple gradle task, called 'instrument'. All it does right now is move through the src folder of the java project and call the instrumenter on every .java file it finds, which copies a modified version of that file somewhere into the build folder. Later I want to use those files to compile the project instead of the originals, but first I also need to instrument project dependencies, because this is a modular project.

Is there an easy way to achieve that without hard-coding the task into each dependency? Because later on this needs to work for a wide variety of project structures. Right now the dependency is declared within the build.gradle file of my main project module, like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
}
```

Also, if somebody could point me into the right direction to compile the src folder with the instrumented .java files in the build folder instead of the original src folder, I would be very grateful.

I originally tried compiling the entire project manually with javac, but that turned out to be way more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you expect, but:

- you could write your own gradle plugin for this
- or instead you can put that task in ROOT/buildSrc/... to be available to all subprojects

further on (and you probably have worked these out yourself in your task:
You can check if a certain dependency (or src configuration) is present in your subprojects, or check on a dependency present:
`configurations.compile.resolve().each { println it.canonicalPath }` or checking if a/your certain custom configuration is present.

concerning the generated source I found e.g.:

- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/right-way-to-generate-sources-in-gradle-7/41141
- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-add-generated-sources-to-compile-classpath-without-adding-them-to-the-main-sourceset/5614